# SQL: Fetching total shares of a customer through multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have 3 tables customer(cid, name, phone) and transactions (cid (reference), fundid, date, shares) and fund (fundid, fund_name).

I am trying to write an sql query that would get me the total number of shares for each customer for each fund.

Here are the sample inserts:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(1, 'Alex', '123456678');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(2, 'Bill', '6323450236');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(3, 'Marie', '8568289912');



INSERT INTO FUND (1, 'Docotel');

INSERT INTO FUND (2, 'Armen');

INSERT INTO FUND (3, 'TD');




INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(1, 2, '2010-2-12', 234); (means shares bought)

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(3, 1, '2010-4-2', 192);

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(1, 2, '2010-4-22', -45); (the '-' means shares sold) 

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(1, 3, '2010-4-26', 220);

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(3, 2, '2010-7-21', 170);
```

I want the sql result to look something like this:

```
Name| Fund_Name | Total_Shares |

Alex Docotel 189

Alex TD 220

Marie Docotel 192

Marie Armen 170
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer.name, fund.fund_name, T1.total_shares
FROM
(
    SELECT cid, fundid, SUM(shares) AS total_shares
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY cid, fundid
) T1
JOIN customer ON T1.cid = customer.cid
JOIN fund ON T1.fundid = fund.fundid
ORDER BY customer.name
```

Comment: Would this take into the result of shares bought and shares sold? I mean would this result in Alex's Docotel shares bought - Alex's Docotel shares sold?

Comment: Yes, I think does what you want.

Comment: Thank you.. it worked like a charm :D .. I just had to add sum(T1.total_shares) to get the results I wanted.